# Macro stops after the first row , automation error

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I was writing a macro and when I run the program, it runs fine when reading the first row but when it loops around and does the second row, I get an error, saids automation problem and the macro quits. I was wondering what's going on that it works fine for the first loop but not the second.

Basically, what I want the macro to do it read rows 8 - 25, if the cell has a date in cell (i) (i being 8, 9, 10, etc..), column B then copy row and paste it to another workbook.

Any body have any ideas? thanks! :)

```
Sub Update()

Dim Request As Workbook
Dim blank As Worksheet
Dim oakfield As Workbook

Set Request = Workbooks("Request_Microbiological_Analysis(blank).xlsm")
Set blank = Request.Worksheets("blank")
Set oakfield = Workbooks.Open("O:\_Public\Quality_Oakfield.xlsm")


With ThisWorkbook

Dim i As Long

For i = 8 To 25

If IsDate(Cells(i, 2)) Then

blank.Cells(i, "A").Resize(, 12).Copy

oakfield.Worksheets("Microlog").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats

ActiveWorkbook.Save

ActiveWorkbook.Close


ElseIf IsEmpty(Cells(i, 2)) Then

MsgBox "Oakfield Quality Updated"

End If

Next i

End With

MsgBox "Quality System Updated"



End Sub
```

Comment: `IsDate(Cells(i, 2))` how does the computer know which `cell` you want here? You know how to do this because later you did `blank.Cells(i, "A")` ^_^

Comment: if the cell has a date, then copy the entire row.

Comment: if the cell doesn't have a date on it, then stop macro. Basically I want it to read column b, rows 8-25 until there is no date on column b and save another workbook when it's done

Comment: You didn't answer my question/missed my point. Did you write the code above???

Comment: Yes I did write it, I'm lost D: D: D:

Comment: hmmm, maybe if I change it to range instead of cells?

Comment: see my solution below. you are closing the workbook on your first iteration, and as such it cannot be accessed the second time around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue here appears to be due to the fact that you close `ActiveWorkbook` in your loop, but then don't open it again. An `automation error` typically occurs when a workbook object is being referenced when it isn't open. You need to wait until after the loop to close your workbook.

Comment: I figured that was the reason after looking online, and tried it. Thanks.

Comment: I never knew the automation error did that, thank you!